# MATLAB using cosh and sinh

Tags: matlab

I am trying the find the inverse Laplace voltage of a circuit, but when I compute it MATLAB output contains sinh and cosh. Is there a way to make MATLAB compute it?

Here is my code:

```
syms s

F=((s^2)+12*s+20)/(s*((s^2)+10*s+4))

f=ilaplace(F)

f=vpa(f,5)
```

Comment: Please edit your question so your code isn't all mashed into one line.

Comment: You can cast to double to get a numeric result: `double(f)`.

Comment: I used but I get an error
`f2=double(f2)



f2=double(vpa(f2,5)`

"Unable to convert expression containing symbolic variables into double array. Apply 'subs' function first to substitute values for variables.

Error in sym/double (line 868)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Related documentation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression for `f` contains the `t` symbol, you have to substitute a value for `t` before you can compute the output at that time `t`; the error message directs you precisely to that solution. I chose `t = 5`, you can change that as you wish.

```
syms s

F = (s^2 + 12*s + 20) / (s*(s^2 + 10*s + 4));
f = ilaplace(F); 
% 5 - 4*exp(-5*t)*(cosh(21^(1/2)*t) + (3*21^(1/2)*sinh(21^(1/2)*t))/14)
f = subs(f, 5);

double(f)
ans =
    4.5083
```